# How can I set my vim or terminal to be possible that if I write function it show document automatically like this image?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

How can I set my vim or terminal to be possible like this image?
This image show me that If you write library or function it show document automatically.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqYcf.gif)

Comment: This looks like bpython. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thank for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay in order to install bpython interpreter, check its [Download page](http://www.bpython-interpreter.org/downloads.html).

To make it easy for you these are the necessary packages that you need to install.

### [setuptools 25.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#code-of-conduct)

### [Pygments 2.1.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygments/2.1.3)

For files with .whl format you can install them with `pip`

```
sudo pip install Pygments-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

---

### [requests 2.10.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/)

### [curtsies 0.2.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/curtsies/0.2.6)

### [greenlet 0.4.10](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet)

### [Bpython Interpreter](http://www.bpython-interpreter.org/)

Last version : [bpython Interpreter last version 15.0](http://www.bpython-interpreter.org/releases/bpython-0.15.tar.gz)

Older version: [List of older version](http://www.bpython-interpreter.org/releases/)

Extract it and execute the command below:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

After installing all the modules and packages you can finally open the bpython interpreter by executing the command in Terminal:

```
bpython
```

Here is a screenshot of mine on Linux

[image]

If you have any questions regarding the installation feel free to comment :)

Comment: DO I have to install all that library for using bpython?

Comment: exactly it will not take too much time

Comment: You are right! Thanks Meninx. I'm sorry it can't be used with Ipython(Jupyter) Notebook :(